# R: Summing values of columns through a loop

Tags: r, loops, calculated-columns

I'm really new to R and this forum, and need help constructing a loop.
(I'm a biology student with almost zero programming experience).

My dataframe has the following (simplified) structure:

```
    a = "TNS"
    b = NA
    c = NA
    d = 21
    e = 37
    f = 1
    g = 39
    h = 29
    df = data.frame (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

In reality my data frame consists of 210 rows and 90 columns, but those other rows are not really of interest to me right now.
What I'm looking for is a way to sum the values of every column which each other, except the first three, and add those results automatically as new columns to the end of my dataframe.
This would preferentially result in a data.frame as follows:

```
    a = "TNS"
    b = NA
    c = NA
    d = 21
    e = 37
    f = 1
    g = 39
    h = 29
    de = 58
    df = 22
    dg = 60
    dh = 50
    ef = 38
    eg = 76
    eh = 66
    fg = 40
    fh = 30
    gh = 68
    df = data.frame (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,de,df,dg,dh,ef,eg,eh,fg,fh,gh)
```

It cannot pair each column more than once. And having run the loop for each pairing I need to do it for each triplet of columns, quartet columns etc.

Why would I want to do this? I need to do this for 85 columns for a biodiversity research project and it would take way too much time to calculate the value for each combination by hand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I really don't have the experience with R to come up with a solution by myself!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `combn` in conjunction with `rowSums`, like this:

```
## This creates the names for the new columns we'll be creating
nam <- combn(names(df)[-c(1, 2, 3)], 2, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))

## Create and assign to your original data.frame
df[nam] <- combn(names(df)[-c(1, 2, 3)], 2, 
                 FUN = function(x) rowSums(df[x], na.rm = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
df
#      a  b  c  d  e  f g h de df dg dh ef eg eh fg fh gh
# 1  TNS NA NA  3  3 10 5 9  6 13  8 12 13  8 12 15 19 14
# 2  TNS NA NA  4  2  3 6 7  6  7 10 11  5  8  9  9 10 13
# 3  TNS NA NA  6  7  7 5 8 13 13 11 14 14 12 15 12 15 13
# 4  TNS NA NA 10  4  2 2 6 14 12 12 16  6  6 10  4  8  8
# 5  TNS NA NA  3  8  3 9 6 11  6 12  9 11 17 14 12  9 15
# 6  TNS NA NA  9  5  4 7 8 14 13 16 17  9 12 13 11 12 15
# 7  TNS NA NA 10  8  1 8 1 18 11 18 11  9 16  9  9  2  9
# 8  TNS NA NA  7 10  4 2 5 17 11  9 12 14 12 15  6  9  7
# 9  TNS NA NA  7  4  9 8 8 11 16 15 15 13 12 12 17 17 16
# 10 TNS NA NA  1  8  4 5 7  9  5  6  8 12 13 15  9 11 12
```

---

Here's the sample data used for this answer:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = "TNS", b = NA, c = NA, 
           matrix(sample(10, 50, TRUE), ncol = 5, 
                  dimnames = list(NULL, c("d", "e", "f", "g", "h"))))
df
#      a  b  c  d  e  f g h
# 1  TNS NA NA  3  3 10 5 9
# 2  TNS NA NA  4  2  3 6 7
# 3  TNS NA NA  6  7  7 5 8
# 4  TNS NA NA 10  4  2 2 6
# 5  TNS NA NA  3  8  3 9 6
# 6  TNS NA NA  9  5  4 7 8
# 7  TNS NA NA 10  8  1 8 1
# 8  TNS NA NA  7 10  4 2 5
# 9  TNS NA NA  7  4  9 8 8
# 10 TNS NA NA  1  8  4 5 7
```

Comment: @JasperBunschoten, no problem. Glad to help out.